# Rutas Laravel 9 API retornan una view en vez de ir al controlador

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Por alguna razón que no puedo terminar de entender ni descubrir, mis rutas definidas en api.php llevan a la vista por default que viene cuando instalas un nuevo proyecto de laravel. Estoy utilizando Laravel 9 e hice la instalacion junto con docker desktop con el comando curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash. Alguien tiene alguna idea de porque sucede esto? Dejo codigo de los archivos pertinentes.

api.php:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController;


Route::prefix('tournament')->name('tournament.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('emulate', [TournamentController::class, 'emulateTournament'])->name('emulate');
});
```

Controlador:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\EmulateTournamentRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\EmulateTournamentResource;
use App\Interfaces\TournamentRepositoryInterface;

class TournamentController extends Controller
{
    private TournamentRepositoryInterface $tournamentRepository;

    public function __construct(TournamentRepositoryInterface $tournamentRepository)
    {
        $this->tournamentRepository = $tournamentRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Emulate a new Tournament
     *
     * @param EmulateTournamentRequest $request
     * @return mixed
     **/
    public function emulateTournament(EmulateTournamentRequest $request)
    {
        $playersIds = $request->only('players');

        if (count($playersIds) < 2) {
            return response([
                'status'   => 'error',
                'message'  => 'TOURNAMENT_NEEDS_TWO_PLAYERS_AT_LEAST'
            ], 400);
        }

        return $this->success(new EmulateTournamentResource($this->tournamentRepository->emulateTournament($playersIds)), 'TOURNAMENT_FINISHED');
    }
}
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon código NO imágenes.

Comment: Gracias! ya lo edito

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Estoy accediendo a http://localhost:80/api/tournament/emulate  las rutas definidas en api.php es la que deje arriba y en web.php tengo unicamente deinido  esto: 

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: Primero que nada gracias por tomarte el tiempo de contestarme. Tu respuesta solucionó mi problema y voy a dejar esta pregunta para futuros programadores que se encuentren con esto. Estoy haciendo las peticiones desde insomnia y no tenia el head Accept: application/json.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a @porloscerros pude solucionar mi problema y era el siguiente:

Estoy haciendo las peticiones desde insomnia y no tenia el head Accept: application/json.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Impecable, nuevamente muchas gracias!